# Java Netty connection timed out

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

I'm using Netty to implement a TCP server on Ubuntu server an I'm facing a weird problem with the connection timeout.

In this server, the client should stay connected a long time without sending any data which seemed to be fine :

```
2015-09-23 02:15:14 INFO  ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter:42 - data
2015-09-23 02:45:14 INFO  ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter:42 - data
```

The client here was able to send two messages after 30 minutes of inactivity without any problem. But in this case :

```
2015-09-23 03:15:14 INFO  ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter:42 - data
2015-09-23 03:26:47 INFO  ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter:155 - Connection timed out
```

The server has thrown a connection times out excpetion even though the client has stood only 10 minutes without sending any message.

And this is the configuration of Netty:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                                throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(
                                    "frameDecoder",
                                    new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
                                            Integer.MAX_VALUE, Delimiters
                                                    .lineDelimiter()));
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new GpsMessageHandler());
                        }
                    })

                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).await();

            f.channel().closeFuture().syncUninterruptibly();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
        }

        finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }

    }
```

I've checked the iptables firewall and everything seems to be ok(all the ports are open).

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you please provide source code of initializing the connection on both sides for both cases?

Comment: Done for the server one.. I can't provide the source code of the client because It's a GPS device..

Answer (score 0):

```
childOption(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 7000)
```

This option handle timeout for every message from client. But in your case ,

```
ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
```

Maybe helps